# How to start a shell script after reboot at a specific point of the script

Tags: shell, scripting, freebsd, bsd

I'm new to shell scripting.
I am trying to automaticate the server basic installation at my work, in this case, a freebsd server.

Now, my question is, if it's possible to execute a shell script and after reboot to proceed automatically at the last point where my script was interrupted by the shutdown?

```
freebsd-update upgrade -r 11.1-RELEASE 
freebsd-update install
shutdown -r now
freebsd-update install
```

Of course, the shutdown of the server in my script stops the whole execution, but is there any opportunity to jump into the script after the system came up again und execute the last command from the commands above?

```
freebsd-update install
```

Comment: You can use `/var/run` to track the steps.  Before each step, you could check if the step file exists and skip the step accordingly.  If the step is executed successfully, create the step file.  At the end, you could remove all the step files.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds great but I don't have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this:

```
run_dir=/var/run/myscript # change the name as appropriate    
check_step() {
  step=$1
  step_file=$run_dir/$step.step.done
  if [ ! -f "$step_file" ]; then
    return 0
  else
    echo "Step $step skipped"
    return 1
  fi
}

step_done()  {
  touch "$run_dir/$1.step.done" && echo finished step $1
}

mkdir -p "$run_dir"
check_step upgrade  && freebsd-update upgrade -r 11.1-RELEASE && step_done upgrade
check_step install1 && freebsd-update install && step_done install1
shutdown -r now
check_step install2 && freebsd-update install && step_done install2
```

- check_step checks if a particular step is already done
- step_done marks the step as done

Comment: Bash is not installed at /bin/bash on FreeBSD.

Comment: Updated the answer to make it POSIX compatible.